# ChartJS onClick() event to update a different chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, chart.js

I am new to Chart.js. I managed to build a couple of charts, but now I want to implement some sort of interaction between them. For example when a user clicks on one of the columns from the first chart the values should update on the other chart. Here is the code I got so far.

This is my js file

```
var barChartData = {
                            labels : ["label1","label2","label3","label4"],

                            datasets : [              
                                {
                                    label: "My dataset",
                                    data:[{!currentMonth_3},{!currentMonth_2},{!currentMonth_1},{!currentMonth}],                                   
                                }]               
                           }

 var chartOptions={
                   "my chart's option"
                    }   


 var doughnutData = [
                    {
                        value: 20,             
                    },
                    {
                        value : 30,            
                    },
                    {
                        value : 40,       
                    },
                    {
                        value : 10,
                    }

                    ];


 var doughnutOptions = { 
                    "my Chart Options
                 }





      window.onload = function(){
                            var ctx = document.getElementById("barchart").getContext("2d");
                            var ctz = document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d");

                            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData,chartOptions);
                            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctz).Doughnut(doughnutData,doughnutOptions);
    }
```

This is my HTML page

```
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

    <body >
        <div id="wrapper" >

               <div id="header">
                  <h1>Title </h1>
               </div>

                <div id="main">  

                        <div id="top">
                             <div class="chart-legend">
                                  <h1 >Chart1 </h1>                   
                             </div>

                             <div class="canvas-container">
                               <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
                             </div>

                         </div>


                        <div id="bottom">
                              <div id="left" >
                                      <div class="chart-legend">
                                         <h1 >Chart2</h1>             
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="canvas-container">
                                          <canvas id="doughnut"></canvas>
                                       </div>

                                  </div>


                            <div id="right">
                            </div>


                                  </div>

                          </div>

                     </div>

                 <div id="footer">
                 </div>

               </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

I basically have 2 charts:

- Chart 1 -> barchar
- Chart 2 ->doughnutchart
- When the user clicks on one of the column from Chart1 the data from Chart2 should change.

I do apologize on behalf of my bad indentation. I edited the code inside this post to make it more easy to understand, hence some code parts might be in a valid working form.

Comment: Which version of Chart js are you using ?

Comment: I am using 1.0.2 Chart.js